# id_number variable returns null when used in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

### index.html.erb

```
<div id="id_number">-</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#commendations_click').click(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      window.location = "<%=j commendations_path(format: 'pdf') %>" 
        + "?idnumber=" + $('#id_number').html() 
        + "&amp;employee_movement_id=" + $('#employee_movements_select').val()
    });

    $('#empname').autocomplete({ 
      source: $('#empname').data('autocomplete-source'), 
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#empname").val(ui.item.last_name + ', ' + ui.item.first_name + ' ' + ui.item.middle_name);
        $("#name").html(ui.item.last_name + ', ' + ui.item.first_name + ' ' + ui.item.middle_name);
        $("#id_number").html(ui.item.id_number);

        $.ajax({
          url: "<%= update_employee_movements_path %>",
          data: { id_number : ui.item.id_number },
          dataType: "script"
        });

        return false;
      }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>Name: " + item.last_name + ', ' + item.first_name + ' ' + item.middle_name + "<br>ID: " + item.id_number + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

  });
</script>
```

### reports_controller.rb

```
def commendations
  emdates = EmployeeMovement.last_2_dates_obtained(params[:employee_movement_id])
  date_from = emdates[0].date_obtained
  date_to   = emdates.length == 1 ? nil : emdates[1].date_obtained
  emp       = Employee.find_by_id_number(params[:id_number])

  ...more code below...
end
```

Kindly take a look at the last line. Here, params[:id_number] will return nil. However, if I change id_number to idnumber in the URL, and call params[:idnumber], I will then get a relevant value.

Why is it that id_number would return nil when accessed from my commendations action? Is there a convention for this? Is the convention on the jquery side or the rails side?

Comment: Your `&amp;` should be simply `&` in a URL.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for the element `#id_number`?

Comment: Hello @Blazemonger, i've updated my question. #id_number is a div tag that gets updated by another event.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your HTML code, the ID of the element is `idnumber` not `id_number`. It is not a convention but a typo in your code.

Comment: Pardon me for asking but how is it that you can determine this as fact enough to be an answer for the OP?

Comment: Hello @emaillenin , it's not a typo. I noticed that id_number doesn't work so I changed it to idnumber. When I apply change in the URL, I also do the same when calling the params[] from my action. Please see my updated question.